# Hе переопределяет путь к PHP on MAMP

Tags: php, macos, path, mamp

у меня на данный момент стоит php 7.1.23

я пытаюсь поставить другой путь данной командой

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/7.3.7/bin:$PATH
```

но при просмотре php -v
я получаю вcе туже старую версию

как правильно переопределить путь?

Comment: `which -a php` что выводит?

Comment: /usr/bin/php вот это. дефолтный путь

Comment: Попробуйте так: `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.7/bin:$PATH"`, далее `source ~/.bashrc`, далее `which -a php` — 7.3.7 должен быть первым в списке.

Comment: cпасибо большое!

Comment: Отметьте ответ как правильный, если Вам не сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `.bashrc` напишите `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.7/bin:$PATH"`, далее выполните `source ~/.bashrc`, далее `which -a php` — 7.3.7 должен быть первым в списке.